# how to handle input form with single name input that has many value?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, input, onchange

i have a table where the table has many rows of data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW8Ed.png)

my table has function which can add multiple row to handle multiple input. so far this function to add multiple rows in my table is works. when i click button to generate multiple empty rows.
this is example code that i used before. this code just record lasted input.

```
const [newInputRows, setNewInputRows] = useState([])
const handleChangeNewRows = (event) => {
    setNewRows({...newInputRows, [event.target.name] : event.target.value})
    console.log(newInputRows)
  }
```

this bellow part of return. this is my code to generate new empty rows::

```
const newRows = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        <tbody>
              {
                insertRows && newRows.map(rows =>
                  <tr key={rows} id={rows}>
                    <td style={setStyle("20px")}></td>
                    {
                      _header.map((column,idc) => column === '_id' ? null : <td key={idc} className="input"><InputRows type="text" name={column} onChange={handleChangeNewRows}/></td>)
                    }
                  </tr>
                 )
               }
        </tbody>
```

as you can see, all of the rows has multiple input with same(single) name. my question is how to handle form input with multiple values in a single input name. because this form will send into backend where the database has 2 field countryCode and Country name.
i want to make this form send to backend to be an array of object like this bellow:

```
[
{countryCode: "A", countryName: "countryA"},
{countryCode: "B", countryName: "countryB"},
{countryCode: "C", countryName: "countryC"}
]
```

how to handle this in reactjs?

Comment: Generate a GUID to associate with each row of data/inputs. Can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you've tried already?

Comment: for the GUI you can see the img link above @DrewReese

Comment: GUID, not GUI, I'm referring to a Globally Unique Identifier, as in, an id to uniquely identify a row for which you want to update state data for since all the inputs share name attributes. If you don't have any row ids, I can help improve your code if you share the MCR code example in your question.

Comment: ohh okay, let me give an example to my posting

Comment: i just put my code that i used to generate new row. @DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue I see is with how you handle updating row data, you are changing the state invariant from array to object and you've no way to uniquely identify the row of data you want to update.

1. I suggest first create a callback to add an `id` to each row new data element.

   ```
   import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

   ...

   const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

   const addRow = () =>
     setRowData((rowData) =>
       rowData.concat({
         id: uuidV4(),
         countryCode: "",
         countryName: ""
       })
     );
   ```
2. Use a curried change handler to close over in scope a row id, and use a functional state update to shallow copy the previous state.

   ```
   const changeHandler = (rowId) => (e) => {
     const { name, value } = e.target;
     setRowData((rowData) =>
       rowData.map((data) =>
         data.id === rowId
           ? {
               ...data,
               [name]: value
             }
           : data
       )
     );
   };
   ```
3. Map the row data and attach the change handlers.

   ```
   {rowData.map((data) => (
     <tr key={data.id}>
       <td>
         <input
           name="countryCode"
           value={data.countryCode}
           onChange={changeHandler(data.id)}
         />
       </td>
       <td>
         <input
           name="countryName"
           value={data.countryName}
           onChange={changeHandler(data.id)}
         />
       </td>
     </tr>
   ))}
   ```

Demo

[image: Edit how-to-handle-input-form-with-single-name-input-that-has-many-value]

[image]

> ```
> [
>   {countryCode: "A", countryName: "countryA"},
>   {countryCode: "B", countryName: "countryB"},
>   {countryCode: "C", countryName: "countryC"}
> ]
> ```

Comment: ig got new problems with event onChange, this code is works. now mycode could save into database. but the last row and the last character that i type in input can't captured. let me give an example. if i type "countryC" my code just capture "country" the letter C is gone. i don't know why

Comment: @rikiyudha Are you enqueueing a state update and then immediately trying to use the state to do something else? Remember that React state updates are asynchronously processed. It seems you are using the state from the current render cycle and not what it *will be* in the next render cycle.

Comment: @rikiyudha Have you still an issue to resolve?

Comment: for input type text i have no issue but i have an issue with input checkbox type and radio input type now @Drew Reese

Comment: @rikiyudha I see. Normally you would/should post a new question for any new issues when the current question is resolved. My guess here is that you need to handle the `checked` property of the `onChange` event. Can you add the new relevant details regarding checkbox/radio inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The output is what you want

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const handleClick = () => {
    list.splice(0, list.length);
    const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].name === "countryName") {
        list.push({
          countryCode: inputs[i - 1].value,
          countryName: inputs[i].value
        });
        setList(list);
      }
    }
    console.log("list: ", JSON.stringify(list));
  };
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="countryCode" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="countryName" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="countryCode" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="countryName" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="countryCode" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="countryName" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```